# Asp.net Detail View

Tags: asp.net, detailview

I am new to this so plz any one give me the example of the Asp.net detail view Control 
with CRUD Operation which is inbuilt in detail view.
If you don't get me please reply me.

I am trying with this,

```
   <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" AutoGenerateRows="false" runat="server" OnItemUpdating="update"
            OnModeChanging="mode">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PrName" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
                <asp:CommandField UpdateText="Update" CancelText="Cancel" DeleteText="Delete" />

            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>


protected void mode(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly)
    {
        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
        FileUpload fl = new FileUpload();
        BindPropertyList();
        fl = (FileUpload)DetailsView1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    }
    else
    {
        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
        BindPropertyList();
    }
}
protected void update(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
    t1 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0];
    DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
    BindPropertyList();
}
protected void delete(object sender, DetailsViewDeleteEventHandler e)
{
}
```

I am using this code but i don't get update click event working but others work fine

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you have name of the update method in lower case in it's definition? You are calling a Update method in detailview with upper U?